# scrollTop() doesn't work with scrolling:touch

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, scroll

I have a problem with the MOBILE_page of this PC_page website of mine:

[Clik here to see](http://www.corioki.com/lista_servizi.php)

As u can see, if u scroll the page and then u click the next or prev arrow on left/right side of the screen, the content scrolls by itself at the top of the page next/prev content.

I am currently use the following code into a click function to obtain the effect:

```
$(function(){
   var cntWid = $('#content').width();
   var scrNum = $('#slider ul').length;
   $('#slider').width(cntWid*scrNum);   
   c = 0;

   $('#arrownext, #arrowprev').click(function(){ 
        var myId = this.id=='fa' ? c++ : c--;
        c = c===-1 ? scrNum-1 : c%scrNum;
        $('#slider').stop().animate({left: -c*cntWid, top:0}, 800); 
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast"); 
        $('#slider').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");                             
   });
});
```

So the PC page has no porblems with this.

Sadly, the mobile version of the same page doesn't scrolls to the top of the content when I use arrows buttons because in the CSS file I defined the #slider div area as:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
```

So, when I click on the arrows, the page move to the left or to the right, but the level of scrolling remains the same.
I would like to see the content setting at the top of the scrolling on mobile devices too as happens in the pc version. 
Unfortunately I really I can't solve this issue.

If I don't use -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch the scrolling effect on the mobile looses its momentum effect but the scrolltop:0 works. I would like to have both.

Any suggestions please?

regards

Matteo :)

Comment: `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");` post with eventListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because mobile devices doesnot recognize `click` event to overcome this issue there is an event of `touchstart touchend`:

```
$('yourselector').on('touchstart click', function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
});
```